# Retrieving and displaying third party Facebook statuses in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm new to Facebook development and I'm running into trouble with what seems like it should be an easy task.  I am building an iOS app for a client, and that client wants to display a number of their most recent status updates in the app, along with a link to their Facebook page.  These statuses should be displayed to the user of the app even if they are not logged into Facebook or do not have a Facebook account saved on their device.

My research so far seems to indicate that I'll need to make a request to the Graph API using a user access token (which I can do successfully in the app using a token copied and pasted from the Graph API Explorer), but it seems that the only way to get a user access token from within the app is to log the user of the app into Facebook using their account credentials.  This is not a good solution because I need to be able to display the client's statuses to the user whether they have are logged into a Facebook account or not.  Is such a thing possible, and if so, how?  I've been all over the docs and can't find a conclusive answer either way.

Answer (score 0):

I know that we would approach it quite differently.  We would have our own web service periodically  pull what we needed off of google and store it on our own server, then we would use AFHTTPClient to pull this information down to our app.  That way we wouldn't have to spoof anything with FaceBook or put any requirments on our users, such as logging into facebook.  It would require that you have a service that your client maintains (or you could easily contract that for a cost).